# djangorestframework user_id violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I've been looking at this a few days now and am getting to pullout my hair so any help would be appreciated.

I have a simple model called package that has a userFrom and userTo

```
class Package(models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  packageid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64, default=uuid_str, editable=False)
  userfrom  = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', editable=False, related_name='userfrom')
  userto  = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', editable=False, related_name='userto')
```

and my views for package has the following to assign the mapping

```
 def pre_save(self, obj):
    print "adding user to object! %s "%self.request.user
    obj.userfrom = self.request.user
```

Hoever it seems that pre_save isn't getting called and the mapping of userid's isn't happening. When I log in with the api and try to push a new package I get the error.

I've tried to map this has closely as possible to the tutorial http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions.html without any luck.

Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
null value in column "userfrom_id" violates not-null constraint

browsing the source to the sql I can see that userfrom_id and userto_id are both null.

Any idea's  much appreciated.

J

Comment: Could you add to the question what your view looks like and what if anything you have in your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue...

You have to call the pre_save in your post with the serialized object:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        self.pre_save(serializer.object) #pass in serializer.object
        serializer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought this thing was a freaking call back the whole time.... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

the method you defined pre_save(), it is not a view, It is a Model method and should be executed rigth before an instance of the object Package is inteded to be saved. What happens is that pre_save does not know the value of the variable "request" because that kind of variable lives in a view function environment and not in the model environment. You are mixing up things.

I think you need something like this:

```
# views.py
def your_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        package_form = PackageForm(request.POST)
        if package_form.is_valid():
            package = package_form.save(commit=False)
            package.userfrom = request.user
            package.save()

            return render(request, 
                'your_template.html', {}
            )
    package_form = PackageForm()
    return render(request, 
                'another_template.html', {}
            )
```

That would be the view. You gonna need a Form something like this:

```
class PackageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        exclude = ('userfrom',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your view class inherits **CreateModelMixin** mixin.

As the [doc](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#methods) states:

> Remember that the pre_save() method is not called by GenericAPIView itself, but it is called by create() and update() methods on the CreateModelMixin and UpdateModelMixin classes.

Comment: Are you able to show a working example of the code? By itself, this doesn't really answer the question.